# Perl extract hash values partially and add it in database into two columns

Tags: xml, perl, hash

I have this data extracted from XML file.

```
$v={ 'CVE-2015-5698' => {
                         'cve_id' => 'CVE-2015-5698',
                         'seq' => '2015-5698',
                         'CVSS_base_score' => '7.5',
                         'CVSS_vector' => 4
                       },
      'CVE-2015-0812' => {
                         'cve_id' => 'CVE-2015-0812
                         'seq' => '2015-0812',
                         'type' => 'CVE',
                         'CVSS_impact_subscore' => '2.9'
                       }

'
```

Question:

1.How to extract cve_id and seq key/value pair from both CVE?

2.Which data structure should i use to save the extracted cve_id and sec so that i can easily use these values to insert in database?

Comment: I don't understand your example data. What tool did you use to print that? That's not Data::Dumper, Data::Printer or Data::Dump. Does `%hash` contain CVE ids and hash refs, and the repeated, indented block of key/values is what's inside of the hash ref? If so, your first question doesn't really make sense. Please use Data::Dumper or another one of the tools I mentioned above to output the data structure.

Comment: @simbabque I am using dumpvalue for printing data.Yes data is of the same format with key/values intended inside the CVE ids and hash refs.I am trying to get 'cve_id' and 'seq' key pair under all the CVE ids and hash refs.

Comment: @simbabque I used Data:Dumper and edited the %data.Could you please help me that how to get all the cve_id and seq under CVE_ids

Comment: You've now edited in a `$v`, but you use parenthesis `()`. Those create a list, but the scalar variable `$v` cannot contain a list. It would become `2` because in scalar context lists return their number of elements. Do you mean `%v`?

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by _sec key/value pair_. There is nothing named _sec_ in the data. Please show what your expected result is, and pay attention to formatting your data correctly. If you want people to help you, please pay attention to details. Details matter.

Comment: @simbabque Sorry,I edited it appropriately now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$v` is a hash reference (`$v={...}`), and that when you say `sec` you mean `seq`, I would use an array of arrays (AoA) as the structure.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $v = { 
      'CVE-2015-5698' => {
                         'cve_id' => 'CVE-2015-5698',
                         'seq' => '2015-5698',
                         'CVSS_base_score' => '7.5',
                         'CVSS_vector' => 4
                       },
      'CVE-2015-0812' => {
                         'cve_id' => 'CVE-2015-0812',
                         'seq' => '2015-0812',
                         'type' => 'CVE',
                         'CVSS_impact_subscore' => '2.9'
                       },
};

my @cve_list;

for my $cve (keys %$v){
    push @cve_list, [$cve, $v->{$cve}{seq}];
}

for (@cve_list){
    print "cve: $_->[0], seq: $_->[1]\n";
    # do your db inserts/work here
}
```

Output:

```
cve: CVE-2015-0812, seq: 2015-0812
cve: CVE-2015-5698, seq: 2015-5698
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detail the explanation but if i want multiple Key /values from CVEs'.For example `cve: CVE-2015-0812, seq: 2015-0812 'CVSS_vector' => 4` I tried doing it using push `@cve_list, [$cve, $v->{$cve}{seq}];` `push @cve_list, [ $v->{$cve}{CVSS_vector}];` and then `print "$_->[0], $_->[1], $_->[2]\n";` Although it print the values firdt two vaues abd then  throws an error **Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string **